# Copy and paste area including merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a block of cells I need to copy and paste to a second sheet. Some of the cells in the block are merged. I have formatted the destination so the cells are also merged where they will receive merged cells.

Is their code to copy and paste as a block, the standard

`Worksheets("9B").Range("C" & a & ":P " & b).Copy Worksheets("Undo").Range("C" & a & ":P" & b)`

will not work with merged cells and I was hoping to avoid having to do each part individually as it is a reasonable size.

Thanks

Comment: Please, try `Worksheets("9B").Range("C" & a & ":P " & b).Copy Worksheets("Undo").Range("C" & a)` (on the same code line). If the range to receive the values is similar formatted, it should work.

Comment: Did you try the above suggestion?

Comment: It didn't work I had to deal with each merged area seperately

Comment: This only means that the ranges in discussion are **Not** formatted in the same way, in terms of merged cells areas... Try manually do this operation for a small test range, only to see that it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have prepared cells in second sheet then do:

```
Sub CopyMerged()

a = 1
b = 10

'First method
Worksheets("9B").Range("C" & a & ":P " & b).Copy
Worksheets("Undo").Range("C" & a & ":P" & b).PasteSpecial

'Second method
Worksheets("Undo").Range("C" & a & ":P" & b).Value = Worksheets("9B").Range("C" & a & ":P " & b).Value

End Sub
```